# How do I use CLI args with vscode built from source?

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron, vscode-extensions

I have ecently built vscode from source following this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute

I can now start vscode using `./scripts/code.sh`.

When I try to use CLI arguments like `./scripts/code.sh --list-extensions` it has no effect.

But how can I use CLI arguments with this built-from-source vscode?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `./scripts/code-sli.sh` if you want to supply arguments.

Examples

```
./scripts/code-sli.sh --list-extensions
./scripts/code-sli.sh --version
./scripts/code-sli.sh path/to/your/extension/
```